# How to store Requested Page url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

By Default Person is Redirected to home page after logging in and if person request for any page without login, it will be automatically redirected to login page.
Now my question is that how to store the page url that the person requested without login so that it can be redirected to that page after it the proof of its authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET Forms Authentication, the module will pass teh initially requested page as query string parameter called `ReturnUrl`. This way when the user enters his credentials and if they are valid you could use this parameter to redirect him.

Comment: sir what is its syntax

Comment: `string returnUrl = Request["ReturnUrl"];`. And then you can redirect to this url using `Response.Redirect(returnUrl);`.

Comment: but sir this code is giving exception 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: url

Comment: That's because you are probably executing this code from a page which doesn't have the ReturnUrl query string parameter passed by.

Comment: sir actually i set the Add.aspx page as Start Page have and Default Page that is Redirected from login page is Home.aspx.

Comment: It is inside the Login page that you can retrieve the `ReturnUrl`. Please read about ASP.NET Forms Authentication to familiarize yourself with the basic concepts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx